# How do I send data to my backend by clicking on save the page with REACT

Tags: reactjs, backend

How is it possible to send these data (Taste, Trust, content of question all questions (which are in Tabs.jsx), everything except the description see the picture please) to my backend by clicking on 'Save the page'.In first part before putting any url inside, I really want to see the data in the console log for now I have nothing printed out except this message :

SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: HTMLButtonElement…}
I have 2 versions but I don't know the difference, what is better to use, I just saw these 2 ways in this forum.

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
 
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    taste: "",
    trust: ""
  });

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("", {
        trust: data.trust,
        taste: data.taste
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
    console.log(e);
  }
  const onError = () => {
    console.log("Error");
  };

  function Checkbox({ value }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);

    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1> {item.name} </h1>
      <div>
        <div className="TextStyle">
          {"Taste "}
          <Dropdown ... />             .
        </div>
       ...
          <Checkbox value={!!item.trust} />
        </div>
       ...
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick= {handleSubmit}
      > Save the content
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

OR the same code with fetch :

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
  const [trust, setTrust] = useState("item.trust");
  const [taste, setTaste] = useState("item.taste");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  let handle = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let res = await fetch("", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          trust: trust,
          taste: taste
        })
      });
      let resJson = await res.json();
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setTaste("");
        setTrust("");
        message("Success");
      } else {
        setMessage("Some error occured");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };  

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={hadle}>
        <h1> {item.name} </h1>
        <div>
          <div className="TextStyle">
            {"Taste "}
            <Dropdown
              style={styles.select}
              options={TASTE}
              defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)}
              styleSelect={colourStyles}
              isMulti={true}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="TextStyle">
            {"Trust "}
            <Checkbox value={!!item.trust} />
          </div>
          <div className="TextStyle"> Description : {item.description} </div>
          <Tabs data={item.questions} />
        </div>
        <button>Save</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Plus I have another form inside my MenuItemDisplay component that is Tabs.jsx. I really don't don't how can I deal with these 2 forms and how to 'trace' these data...

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/MenuItemDisplay.jsx:0-1869)

Comment: Have you tried using an API or something like JSON to send the response ?

Comment: And what is in the backend? is it API or anything else?

Comment: Yes an API, I have my url endpoint already done.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the following approaches.

## Using a `form` element

You need to send the form data to the backend using AJAX calls. The most conventional way to do so is to use a *JSX* `form` element.

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
  ... 
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h1> {item.name} </h1>
      <div>
        <div className="TextStyle">
          {"Taste "}
          <Dropdown
            style={styles.select}
            options={TASTE}
            defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)}
            styleSelect={colourStyles}
            isMulti={true}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="TextStyle">
          {"Trust "}
          <Checkbox value={!!item.trust} />
        </div>
        <div className="TextStyle"> Description : {item.description} </div>
        <Tabs data={item.questions} />
      </div>
      <button type="submit"> Save the page</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

## Using a `handleSubmit` callback to the save button

Another way to do it using the `button` to send the request to the backend when clicked.

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
      ... 
      return (
        <>
          <h1> {item.name} </h1>
          <div>
            <div className="TextStyle">
              {"Taste "}
              <Dropdown
                style={styles.select}
                options={TASTE}
                defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)}
                styleSelect={colourStyles}
                isMulti={true}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="TextStyle">
              {"Trust "}
              <Checkbox value={!!item.trust} />
            </div>
            <div className="TextStyle"> Description : {item.description} </div>
            <Tabs data={item.questions} />
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}> Save the page</button>
        </>
      );
    }
```

All you need to do is define the `handleSubmit` callback. If you use the `form` element, you'd need to prevent the default form submission behavior.

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // if you use the form tag
// validate the data here
// use fetch or axios or any other 3rd party library to send data to the back end
// receive response from backend
// do something with the response 
}
```

Comment: In my Tabs.jsx component I use also a form, will there be issue? I didn't put the Tabs code in my issue because it says "mostly code", but I give you the link for the code. Do you think it will work with my Tabs??

Comment: A form inside a form will be problematic. In that case, use the divs with button based callbacks

Comment: I've changed my code MenuItemDisplay.jsx and tried to 'trace' the data. I'm not able to see the data in the console except this message : yntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: HTMLButtonElement…}. For information I didn't put the url, I really want to see the data in the console log before sending to my backend please

Comment: can you please check my code, I've made some modif but I don't know how to deal with these 2 forms and keep a traceability of my data

Comment: Do you have a github repo?

Comment: Nope all my code, is in the sandbox link

Comment: I've slightly modified my question, I've just added another way to do, but which one is the best  ??